# Upload image from URL to type file input in selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, url, upload, photo

I am trying to upload pictures into a type='File' field with a URL and not the physical file on my computer. I am using windows OS, selenium, and Python. My code works fine if I download a picture and provide my computer file path. However, I have a massive list of the URLs in a csv, and I would prefer to do this without having to download all of the pictures to my computer. If I physically click the upload button, and paste the URL in, it uploads just fine. But not when I do it through selenium. Which is why I am convinced there must be a way to do it without DLing the pictures. Thanks for any assistance.

```
drop = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
drop.send_keys("PICTURE URL")

Message: File not found:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
drop.send_keys("PICTURE URL")
```

Comment: explain the "Why" to prevent downvoting. EoR.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately that gives the error message file not found. I actually intended to sent that code in my original post. I tried so many things that I accidently copied the code that aslo had the 'driver.get' piece, which I knew would not be the answer. Right now, I am running a loop to download the photo onto my computer, but I am still hopeful that this is an unnecessary step. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MB13534 , I just realize I misunderstood your question, I thought you just made a syntax error at `driver.get("PICTURE URL")`. Could you provide more information, such as the url you are testing or code snippet?